# Select specific row from mysql table

Tags: mysql, select, row-number

Ideally I need a query that is equivalent to

```
select * from customer where row_number() = 3
```

but that's illegal.

**I can't use an auto incremented field.**

row_number() is the row that needs to be selected.

How do I go about this?

EDIT: Well, I use iSql*plus to practice, and using limit and auto_increment is illegal for some reason. I ended up creating a sequence and a trigger and just upped the id by 1 every time there was an entry.

Comment: What do you mean by `row_number()`?  Records are not ordered in MySQL.  You need to identify your desired data some other way, based on their content.

Comment: @eggyal: Standard ANSI SQL does have a `row_number()` function (although Marlon's usage would be incorrect) but MySQL does not support that (as so many other modern SQL features)

Answer (score 109, accepted):

You can use `LIMIT 2,1` instead of `WHERE row_number() = 3`.

As the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html) explains, *the first argument specifies the offset of the first row to return, and the second specifies the maximum number of rows to return*.

Keep in mind that it's an 0-based index. So, if you want the line number *n*, the first argument should be *n-1*. The second argument will always be *1*, because you just want one row. For example, if you want the line number *56* of a table `customer`:

```
SELECT * FROM customer LIMIT 55,1
```

Comment: What does LIMIT have to do with this problem?

Comment: @Starx If @MarlonBrando wants simply the third row of his result, not regarding any technical ID, `LIMIT` is the solution.

Comment: this actually works, and is indeed the solution to the problem yet ;)

Comment: @nawfal, How will `row_number() = 3 LIMIT 3,1` return a valid result?

Comment: @Starx Yeah, of course, you have to remove the `WHERE row_number() = 3` of your query...

Comment: This worked great for me. I have a quiz database and I want to display each row of the table on a separate page with the question and answers. A next button keeps track of the page number. My PHP/MySql Limit statement is: LIMIT $pageNumber, 1

Answer (score 8):

You cannot select a row like that. You have to specify a field whose values **will be 3**

Here is a query that will work, if the field you are comparing against is `id`

```
select * from customer where `id` = 3
```

Answer (score 6):

```
SET @customerID=0;
SELECT @customerID:=@customerID+1 AS customerID
FROM CUSTOMER ;
```

you can obtain the dataset from SQL like this and populate it into a java data structure (like a List) and then make the necessary sorting over there. (maybe with the help of a comparable interface)

Comment: this approach is highly inefficient for large datasets

Answer (score 2):

SQL tables are not ordered by default, and asking for the n-th row from a non ordered set of rows has no meaning as it could potentially return a different row each time unless you specify an ORDER BY:

```
select * from customer order by id where row_number() = 3
```

(sometimes MySQL tables are shown with an internal order but you cannot rely on this behaviour). Then you can use `LIMIT offset, row_count`, with a 0-based offset so row number 3 becomes offset 2:

```
select * from customer order by id
limit 2, 1
```

or you can use `LIMIT row_count OFFSET offset`:

```
select * from customer order by id
limit 1 offset 2
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add an auto generated id field in the table and select by this id

```
SELECT * FROM CUSTOMER WHERE CUSTOMER_ID = 3;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your table will need to be created with a unique ID field that will ideally have the AUTO_INCREMENT attribute. example:

```
CREATE TABLE Persons
(
P_Id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
LastName varchar(255) NOT NULL,
FirstName varchar(255),
PRIMARY KEY (P_Id)
)
```

Then you can access the 3rd record in this table with:

```
SELECT * FROM Persons WHERE P_Id = 3
```