# Get the nth row

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I have a table of sales belonging to various customers.

A customer can have more than one sale.

How do I figure out the nth sale for each customer/sale?

I am using Laravel but a plain MySQL answer would be just as good.

My query builder is:

```
$q = DB::table('sales AS S')
        ->select(DB::raw('CONCAT("row_", S.id) AS DT_RowId'),
            'S.id', 'S.created_at', 'users.name AS agent',
            DB::raw('CONCAT(C.first_name, " ", COALESCE(C.last_name, "")) AS name'), 'S.net',
            DB::raw('(S.net - P.base_buy_price) AS margin'),
            DB::raw('((S.net - P.base_buy_price)/P.base_price * 100) AS margin_percent'))
        ->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'S.user_id')
        ->join('customers AS C', 'C.id', '=', 'S.customer_id')
        ->join('products AS P', 'P.id', '=', 'S.product_id')
        ->get();
```

---

**Clarification**

Lets say customer A has bought three times, on dates 2015-06-12, 2015-06-17 and 2016-01-17.

In the results I want each one of those rows telling me which sale is the nth i.e.:

2015-06-12 - 1st sale

2015-06-17 - 2nd sale

2016-01-17 - 3rd sale

---

```
...
DB::raw('(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM sales WHERE sales.created_at <= S.created_at AND sales.customer_id = C.id) AS nth')
...
```

Seems very inefficient?

Comment: `LIMIT n, 1` is that what you want?

Comment: Already answered: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10457458/select-specific-row-from-mysql-table. But @CodeBird is correct. Google is your friend.

Comment: @CodeBird I was thinking it would be some kind of subquery that orders the sales for each customer by date?

Comment: @imperium2335 I don't know what exactly you want, but `LIMIT n, 1` will get you the nth record, you can order by whatever you want... Maybe clarify your question a bit more...

Comment: You can still order the query - but that is dependent on your table structure and where the sale date is located. Just add some form of ORDER BY and then use a limit function if available - not all db's sql variants have it however. Not familiar with Laravel.

Comment: Please see my edit. The suggested answer is not what I need btw.

Comment: @Barmar please see my edit to see how it is different.

Comment: That's not getting the Nth row, it's getting the row number for each row.

Comment: What you want is the rank, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3333665/mysql-rank-function/3333697#3333697