# UPDATE particular row in MYSQL using a row number

Tags: mysql, database, sql-update, row

How to update a particular row from MYSQL DB when v r given a row number liek update username at row =5 , n nothing else is given , v dont want 2 use the WHERE Clause , all v know is row number

so how ??

```
UPDATE  users set status=7 limit 5,1; // this is not working error in sql syntax
```

want 2 update 6th row

users=table name

same what will b the syntax for delete statement for the same operation ?

Comment: 6th row based on what? What's the sorting order?

Comment: mysql the row r not sorted then get appended at the end

Comment: i m luking 4 a better ans , post it if i like it i will accept urs

Comment: Table in mysql are considered to be unordered set of data unless you explicitly specify an order like `ORDER BY <some field>`. So in your case what's that `<some field>`?

Comment: I m not ordering them at all , i m asking 4 he data as it has been appended in the table as it is .Say users keep entering their name n d data keeps getting appended at the bottom , i m calling them in the order the were added in the database . means data gets appended in the bootom , so 1st user who registered comes 1st n last in d last

Comment: i have got my ans thnx

Comment: Btw, Are you playing with accepting answer? I noticed initially you accepted `GEEkSpoTTed's` answer then `Dev Joel's` answer then again unchecking `Dev Joel's answer` you accepted `GEEkSpoTTed's` answer.

Comment: @ 1000111   I m getting this error  when i use ur statement with java NetbeansThis version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery'

Comment: next time plz dont make any allegations

Comment: IT hurts :( u hurt my feelings :(

Comment: Sorry if I hurt u. Just told what did it seem like.

Comment: @1000111 - your intuition was spot on, they were [sockpuppet accounts](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57682/how-should-sockpuppets-be-handled-on-stack-exchange). It has been corrected by the moderators.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read this post:   [Select specific row from mysql table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10457458/select-specific-row-from-mysql-table)

Now once u have selected a row,find a column whose data is unique say id or username ,email ,anything that is unique for a row. Lets say username is unique for ur table

Then do this

```
SELECT username FROM customer LIMIT 5,1;
```

Store it in a variable if u r using java/php/etc. now say u stored in variable var. then using this run another sql command

```
update users set status=7 where username=var ;
```

//var is the varible name that u assigned value to.

Answer (score 1):

you can try something like a nested where the limit accepts two parameters 0 and 2 start where number of rows

```
UPDATE users SET status=1
WHERE userid IN (
 SELECT userid FROM (
     SELECT userid FROM users 
     LIMIT 0, 2
 ) tmp

);
```

Comment: You need an alias for a subquery