# How do I return a specific row number in mysql without using the where clause?

Tags: mysql, sql

How do I return a specific row number (row 60) in MySQL without using the where clause?

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE
```

Comment: SELECT * FROM `my_table` LIMIT 0,60

Comment: What do you mean by _"specific 60 number row"_?

Comment: I mean to say, i have number of rows in table eg. (1-100) or i want to get 60 number row without using WHERE [PRIMARY_COLUMN]=60;

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Select specific row from mysql table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10457458/select-specific-row-from-mysql-table)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM my_table ORDER BY `[column name]` `[ASC or DESC]` LIMIT 0,60
```

Comment: this return 0-60 numbers of rows i want only 60 number row.

Comment: So change it to *59,1* instead of *0,60*

Comment: Why do you not use `WHERE` ? You can do as Draken said, but if your table is not ordered or if you have some duplicates numbers, it will not work.